# How to find numbers of legs of table

Tags: python, opencv

I am really stuck about this, I have this image [image]
and I need to find number of legs. It means, when I execute the code, the output would give me "4"
and I tried 2 ways one of it with the edge detector

```
# import the required library
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class Point:
    x = 0
    y = 0

# read the image
img = cv2.imread('Table.png')
  
# convert image to gray scale image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  
# detect corners with the goodFeaturesToTrack function.
corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, 27, 0.01, 10)
corners = np.int0(corners)
  
# we iterate through each corner, 
# making a circle at each point that we think is a corner.
for i in corners:
    x, y = i.ravel()
    print("x: " + str(x) + " y: " + str(y))
    cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 3, 255, -1)
  
plt.imshow(img), plt.show()
```

I wrote this code and get this result

[image]
but I don't know what will I do after that. Can you guys give me a route. But before finish my question, I also tried canny algorithm and It draw all table and give me a "1" for result. If I can seperate the all part of table maybe can find number of legs. anyway I am still confused.

Comment: if that's the only input picture, your code could simply be `print(4)`. show us different inputs that are to be expected

Comment: I mean it could be any table and the code should give us a number of legs of table. for example, in that picture there are four legs and how can i reach that information? with the edge detection or something different else? and also the image could be different table for example, could be a table with a one leg in the middle of table. then the output will be 1.
for example,
https://sc04.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1rjy8LVXXXXbyXVXXq6xXFXXXm.jpg

I mean, how can do that. maybe all my code is wrong. I wanna know a route. If you understand me you can give me a route and I will try that

Comment: "any table"... there are tables where "legs" isn't an applicable concept. and you have said nothing about the view/perspective of the picture either. a topdown view would be useless in most cases. a bottom-up view might be fun. a sideways view might hide one leg behind another, and you can't count that then. all kinds of assumptions would have to be made. -- you might wanna calculate a mask first, that labels "table" vs background. then you could find a suitable horizontal line, and count the number of background-table-background transitions. if you hit the legs... -- train a neural network?

Comment: The first idea that comes to mind is to flip the image by 180 degrees then plot the histogram of the image. By looking at the histogram, you can determine the number of spikes which should tell you the number of legs